# Django 1.8 serving static files during deployment

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

My project runs fine on the local sever but during deployment on `Heroku`, I get the following error

```
Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run: $ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

I understand this is due to `STATIC_ROOT` settings in `settings.py`, but I can't seem to point to the location of the static files properly.
This is my folder structure.

```
C:/
 /Users
   /Mac
   /denv
    /musicpro
        /musicpro
        /featureapp
           /static
                /featureapp
                   /css
                   /img
                   /js
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'musicpro/featureapp/static/featureapp/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
 )
```

Comment: Which directory are you deploying to Heroku?

Comment: the musicpro directory inside denv

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` has to be an absolute path.

Comment: So should it be STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Mac/musicpro/featureapp/static/featureapp'

Comment: Did you run the suggested command? What was the output?

Comment: I did but I got the following error - `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\
Users\\Mac\\denv\\musicpro\\static' . Is the wrong path shown here is because of STATIC_URL ?